# How to optimize this slow MSSQL query?

Tags: sql-server

Here is my mssql query:

```
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ii.item_id ASC) AS Row,
        ii.item_id, 
        ii.item_description, 
        ii.item_function_id, 
        ib.brand_name, 
        if.name, 
        ipr.part_number, 
        ipr.default_part_number, 
        imn.model_name , 
        imn.is_default,
        img.model_group_name, 
        ims.model_series_name , 
        imf.model_family_name, 
        icg.name as cig_name, 
        ips.proxy_set_name, 
        icn.cartridge_name, 
        (SELECT SUM((quantity - quantity_on_hold - quantity_unposted) * uofm) FROM warehouse_inventory where  sage_item_id = ii.item_id) as qty, 
        ip.item_price FROM ii  

LEFT JOIN ib ON ib.brand_id = ii.brand_id
LEFT JOIN if ON if.id = ii.item_function_id
LEFT JOIN ipr ON ipr.item_id = ii.item_id

LEFT JOIN imn ON imn.model_id in 
    (SELECT  frv.child FROM frv WHERE frv.id = 4 AND frv.parent in 
        (SELECT  frv.parent FROM frv WHERE frv.id = 5 AND frv.child = ii.item_id ) )

LEFT JOIN img on img.model_group_id in 
        (SELECT  frv.parent FROM frv WHERE frv.id = 5 AND frv.child = ii.item_id ) 

LEFT JOIN imf on imf.model_family_id in 
    (SELECT  frv.child FROM frv WHERE frv.id = 15 AND frv.parent in
            (SELECT  frv.parent FROM frv WHERE frv.id = 5 AND frv.child = ii.item_id ) ) 

LEFT JOIN ims on ims.model_series_id in 
    (SELECT  frv.parent FROM frv WHERE frv.id = 9 AND frv.child in
        (SELECT  frv.child FROM frv WHERE frv.id = 4 AND frv.parent in 
            (SELECT  frv.parent FROM frv WHERE frv.id = 5 AND frv.child = ii.item_id ) ) )

LEFT JOIN icg ON icg.item_compatible_group_id in 
    (SELECT  frv.parent FROM frv WHERE frv.id = 25 AND frv.child = ii.item_id )

LEFT JOIN ips ON ips.proxy_set_id in 
    (SELECT  frv.parent FROM frv WHERE frv.id = 2 AND frv.child = ii.item_id )

LEFT JOIN icn ON icn.cartridge_id in 
    (SELECT  frv.child FROM frv WHERE frv.id = 13 AND frv.parent = ii.item_id )

LEFT JOIN ip ON ip.item_id = ii.item_id AND ip.sales_interface_id = 40

WHERE ii.is_deleted = 'false' 
ORDER BY ii.item_id  ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

The task is to get from db top 100 items and to put them in a table. The problem is: the columns `part_number` and `model_name` have multiple values for the same item_id, so when executing this query, if an item have 100 different model_names then it is displayed 100 times. And because of this "OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY" is not working. Is any way to fix this and optimize the query ?

I'm working with coldfusion and there is a way to hide all duplicates() but the query is not working when I try to display 100 different items(getting the 503 error). For Example, when I set "OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5000 ROWS ONLY" I get only 39 distinct rows to show in table.

Comment: It would be easier to answer the questio if You prepare DB schema and test data in SqlFiddle

Comment: You can anyway optimise your query but you can also group the query with `item_id` using `cfoutput` with `maxrow=100`.

Comment: **First**, replace all the `In` operators with exists. **Second**, you might want to use `TOP 100` instead of `offset.. fetch`. **Third**, check your execution plan.

Comment: I removed the ColdFusion tag on this as it has nothing to do with ColdFusion whatsoever.

Comment: Also please consider adding SQL Server version.

Comment: @acesta, is this resolved? You made a question edit to that effect - if so, please add an answer, thanks!

Comment: One thing to do is get rid of all correlated subqueries and use joins instead.  You may need to use derived tables but correlated subquereis in the joins and the selects are performance killers.

Answer (score 0):

You should join to a table which was DISTINCTed **before** the JOIN.

You could use a CTE or an `OUTER APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT... FROM item_model_name )`

Don't know your data but a "TOP 1" could help also.